# Help approximating the leading eigenvalue of this Jacobian

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, stability-in-odes, jacobian

I have a system of 4 ordinary differential equations with positive parameters, which has two stable fixed points. The Jacobian matrix evaluated at the first equilibrium leads easily to finding the conditions for linear stability. These conditions are necessary but are not sufficient for the second equilibrium to be stable. At the second equilibrium, the determinant of the Jacobian is:

\begin{equation*}
  \small
  \boldsymbol{J}  =
  \begin{pmatrix}
    % pds of Capital
    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
    % pds of Inventory
    0 &
    - q - \frac{ b }{ 4 }&
    - \frac{ b }{ 4 }      &
    0 \\
    % pds of Demand
    0 & 0 & - c & - c \big( \frac{k b}{a + \frac{b}{2}} \big)^2 \\
    % pds of Price
    0 &
    - d \big( \frac{a + \frac{b}{2}}{\kappa b} \big)^2 &
    d \big( \frac{a + \frac{b}{2}}{\kappa b} \big)^2 &
    0\\
  \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}

which has characteristic polynomial $\rho(\lambda)$:

\begin{equation}
\rho(\lambda) = -\lambda \Big[ -\lambda^3 - (a + b + c) \lambda^2 - c(a+b+d) \lambda - cd(a+b) \Big]
\end{equation}

Using the Routh-Hurwitz criterion, I know the the 3rd order polynomial inside the bracket has negative roots always (all parameters are positive), which means the remaining eigenvalue must control the second equilibrium's stability. However, the remaining eigenvalue is zero, so the linearisation fails.

I have been attempting to approximate the leading eigenvalue by taking the Taylor series approximation around the point $a \approx 0$ but I haven't been having much luck. That is, making $\lambda = \lambda_0 + \lambda_{1} a + \lambda_{2} a^2 + ...$ in $\rho(\lambda)$ above, and computing $\lambda_0$, $\lambda_1$, $\lambda_2$ etc. at $a = 0$, just returns each coefficient equal to zero, so it seems that the Taylor series approximation is also failing in higher powers.

Does anyone know how I can assess the stability of the second equilirium? Thank you

Comment: Since an eigenvalue is zero the linearization cannot provide a classification at all. The linearization also doesn't really mean very much when performed at a non-equilibrium point. You must actually assess directly what happens in the nonlinear dynamics when you make a perturbation in a direction which has some component in the direction of this last eigenvector. Most likely the worst case scenario for stability is when you move in that exact direction, though there is no theorem that guarantees this as far as I know.

Comment: On the upside, the last eigenvector is easily seen to be $(1,0,0,0)^T$, so maybe it is easy to see how the evolution behaves when you perturb from the equilibrium in that direction.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that one row (or one column) of the matrix is $0$ implies that it is singular,
and thus has an eigenvalue of $0$.  That means that you can't decide the stability by just looking at this Jacobian.  On the other hand, you do know in what direction to look for  potential trouble: the first coordinate direction.  Seeing what happens (in the nonlinear system) to points near the equilibrium in that direction may help decide.

Comment: Thanks. The book I have been learning from shows a perturbation method to approximate the leading eigenvalue for borderline cases, which is where I was going. It seems that the second equilibrium is stable to small pulse perturbations but large perturbations knock it out of equilibrium and lead to unstable growth. Whereas even large perturbations cause the first equilibrium of the system to remain stable.

Comment: There's no need to "approximate the leading eigenvalue" here: you know it's $0$.  "Stable" or "unstable" is, by definition, about small perturbations.  What happens for large perturbations is not in the purview of the theory of stability.